# Webpack - How should I include my generated css for prod/qa/dev environments?

Tags: css, webpack

I've added **.scss** styling to my site. The .scss files sit next to their .jsx components.

I reference the styles in .jsx like this:

```
import styles from './guest-card.component.scss'
...
<Card className={styles.card}>
```

Everything looks great when I run my local server `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.cold.conf.js`

When I build for distributing the app, such as Development machine or QA machine I run `npm run build`. This builds a dist folder with everything compiled.

When I view my site on a dev/qa server my styles are missing.

Looking in the dist folder I see a /static/css/app.css with my compiled styles. Great! The styles look correct.

**My question: What do I do to include these /static/css/app.css in my production site?** I tried adding a `<link rel="stylesheet" ...` to include it and im sure that would work but would give a 404 on my local machine.

Whats the correct way of having styles built

So my question is: 
My question is - how do I get my app to reference this new app.css? If I add a

**build.js**

```
'use strict';
require('./check-versions')();

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

const ora = require('ora');
const rm = require('rimraf');
const path = require('path');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config = require('../config');
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.prod.conf');

const spinner = ora('building...');
spinner.start();

rm(path.join(config.build.assetsRoot, config.build.assetsSubDirectory), err => {
  if (err) throw err;
  webpack(webpackConfig, function (err, stats) {
    spinner.stop();
    if (err) throw err;
    process.stdout.write(stats.toString({
      colors: true,
      modules: false,
      children: false,
      chunks: false,
      chunkModules: false
    }) + '\n\n');

    if (stats.hasErrors()) {
      console.log(chalk.red('  Build failed with errors.\n'));
      process.exit(1)
    }

    console.log(chalk.cyan('  Build complete.\n'));
    console.log(chalk.yellow(
      '  Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.\n' +
      '  Opening index.html over file:// won\'t work.\n'
    ))
  })
});
```

**webpack.prod.conf.js**

```
const paths = require('./paths');
const utils = require('./utils');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config = require('../config');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
  ? require('../config/test.env')
  : require('../config/prod.env');

const webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      extract: true,
      usePostCSS: true
    })
  },
  devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? config.build.devtool : false,
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].js'),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].js')
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      settings: `${paths.settings}/dist.js`
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': env
    }),
    // UglifyJs do not support ES6+, you can also use babel-minify for better treeshaking: https://github.com/babel/minify
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      },
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      parallel: true
    }),
    // extract css into its own file
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].css'),
      // set the following option to `true` if you want to extract CSS from
      // codesplit chunks into this main css file as well.
      // This will result in *all* of your app's CSS being loaded upfront.
      allChunks: false,
    }),
    // Compress extracted CSS. We are using this plugin so that possible
    // duplicated CSS from different components can be deduped.
    new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
      cssProcessorOptions: config.build.productionSourceMap
      ? { safe: true, map: { inline: false } }
      : { safe: true }
    }),
    // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
    // you can customize output by editing /index.html
    // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
        ? 'index.html'
        : config.build.index,
      host: '@_host_@',
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: false,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
        // more options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      },
      // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
    // keep module.id stable when vender modules does not change
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
    // enable scope hoisting
    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
    // split vendor js into its own file
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks(module) {
        // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
        return (
          module.resource &&
          /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
          module.resource.indexOf(paths.nodeModules) === 0
        );
      }
    }),
    // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
    // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'manifest',
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    // This instance extracts shared chunks from code splitted chunks and bundles them
    // in a separate chunk, similar to the vendor chunk
    // see: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#extra-async-commons-chunk
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'app',
      async: 'vendor-async',
      children: true,
      minChunks: 3
    }),

    // copy custom static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: paths.static,
        to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ]),

    // copy any extra assets to root dist
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: `${paths.root}\\web.config`,
        to: config.build.dist,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ])
  ]
});

if (config.build.productionGzip) {
  const CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
      asset: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: new RegExp(
        `\\.(${
        config.build.productionGzipExtensions.join('|')
        })$`
      ),
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
  );
}

if (config.build.bundleAnalyzerReport) {
  const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin());
}

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

**webpack.base.conf.js**

```
const paths = require('./paths');
const utils = require('./utils');
const config = require('../config');

module.exports = {
  context: paths.root,
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.jsx'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    alias: {
      '@': paths.src,
      api: paths.api,
      settings: `${paths.settings}/local.js`
    }
  },
  externals: {
    bamboraCheckout: 'customcheckout'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...(config.dev.useEslint ? [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        enforce: 'pre',
        include: [paths.src, paths.test],
        options: {
          formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter'),
          emitWarning: !config.dev.showEslintErrorsInOverlay
        }
      }] : []),
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [paths.src, paths.test]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**webpack.cold.conf.js**

```
const paths = require('./paths');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const devWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.hot.conf.js');

module.exports = new Promise(resolve => {
  devWebpackConfig.then(base => {
    let webpackConfig = merge(base, {
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          api: `${paths.api}/fakes`
        }
      }
    });
    resolve(webpackConfig);
  })
});
```

Comment: Check that your dist folder contains css files.

Comment: It does! app.css with my css in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you miss link to your generated style file in index.html then you should search for problem here, because this plugin is responsible for it

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
        ? 'index.html'
        : config.build.index,
      host: '@_host_@',
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: false,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
        // more options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      }
```

I just looked through plugin documentation, probably you need to remove inject: false. Default is true, and is putting your assets into index.html